# intercept or override javascript function of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am new in javascript and jquery.

I have created a class having some functions in javascript.
My javascript class is written in a .js file.

**common.js**

```
var myGeneralClass = {
    _show : function() {
        console.log("showing some divs here");
    },
    _hide : function() {
        console.log("hiding some divs here");
    }
}
```

_show() and _hide() functions are *bind to some events*.

Now I have jsp file, from where final html is rendered.

myGeneralClass methods are called from various jsp files.

Some jsp script want to add some code in _show() and _hide() methods according to there need.

for eg :

**employee.jsp**

```
<script>
    //want to add some lines of js code to _show() method plus its default code.
    // intercept _show() method
    _interceptShow : function() {
        console.log("this line is custom for employee");
    },

    // override _show() method
    _overrideShow : function() {
        console.log("this line is custom for employee");
        console.log("showing some divs here");
    }
</script>
```

Can I override OR intercept methods in javascript?

Can it be possible ?

If yes then how?

Comment: Sure, just do `myGeneralClass._show = function() {...` and you're overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding more code in method: 
use this:

```
var temp = myGeneralClass._show;
myGeneralClass._show = function(){ 
  temp(); 
  // more code
}
```

for overriding:

```
myGeneralClass._show = function(){ 
// new code
}
```

Comment: what happens to the arguments?

Comment: same can be passed or used in the new method as needed.